# ReactNative Expo 2d-context How to to drawImage and get base64 data

Tags: react-native, expo

Am trying to use expo-2d-context lib in my react native app : https://github.com/expo/expo-2d-context
However am unable to draw image on canva nor i can get base64 data via `toDataURL` function

so any idea how to draw image and get base64 data from canva.

sample code

```
import { GLView } from 'expo-gl';
import Expo2DContext from 'expo-2d-context';
import React from 'react';
import {Image} from 'react-native';
export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <GLView
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            onContextCreate={this._onGLContextCreate}
          />
        );
    }
    _onGLContextCreate = (gl) => {
        var ctx = new Expo2DContext(gl);
        ctx.translate(50,200)
        ctx.scale(4,4)
        ctx.fillStyle = "grey";
        ctx.fillRect(20, 40, 100, 100);
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fillRect(30, 100, 20, 30);
        ctx.fillRect(60, 100, 20, 30);
        ctx.fillRect(90, 100, 20, 30);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(50,70,18,0,2*Math.PI);
        ctx.arc(90,70,18,0,2*Math.PI);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.fillStyle = "grey";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(50,70,8,0,2*Math.PI);
        ctx.arc(90,70,8,0,2*Math.PI);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(70,40);
        ctx.lineTo(70,30);
        ctx.arc(70,20,10,0.5*Math.PI,2.5*Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();
        
        // draw image
      var img = new Image();
      
      img.onload = () => {
        this.ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0,  width,  height);
        this.ctx.flush();
        
        // get base64 image data
        var b64 = gl.toDataURL();
        
      };        
       img.src = "https://miro.medium.com/max/480/1*F6tkVg8eDXITOSA91Mh0kw.png";
    }
}
```